# SSIS WMI System Event Watcher

Tags: events, ssis, wmi, system

I am currently working with a WMI System Event Watcher in a control flow task that is tied to another sequence container.  The WMI system event watcher fires just fine, but only does it once.  Is there a way I can get it to reset after a successful run?  I have tried setting the watcher to "Watch for the event again" and I've even put the event watcher into a for loop with an infinite loop, but again the problem there is, the watcher will keep running and nothing else happens.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.